# Deserialize an exception with InnerExceptions

Tags: json, exception, serialization

I feel like a dope not being to figure this out but my exposure to JSON is quite limited and I haven't been able to find anything that seems to apply. At least that I can understand.

I *think* this should be super simple.

I have the simple class below that I'm using to deserialize an exception from my webapi call. I just realized today that I was losing the inner exceptions so I'm trying to add that in. I somehow want to get to that innermost exception. I attempted to nest it by adding the InnexerException property. At first I made it of type "ApiSoftException".

Rather than ramble on about my failed attempts, I'm hoping someone has done something like this before.

Thanks!

```
    public class ApiSoftException
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    *public string InnerException { get; set; }*

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this working. I don't understand why my first test didn't work because I could swear that I tried this. By making the inner exception property of the same type the de-serialization seems to support recursive assignment.

So, with the following class it seems to work.

```
    public class ApiSoftException
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public ApiSoftException InnerException { get; set; }

}
```